# Approximation of Lebesgue-integrable functions by continuous functions.

Tags: measure-theory

I want to prove that if $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue-integrable, then for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ continuous such that $\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f-g|<\epsilon$ (I will write the integral simply $\displaystyle\int|f-g|$).

I already know how to approximate $f$ by simple functions.

Now, in the following link:

[Finding simple, step, and continuous functions to satisfy Lebesgue integral conditions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76931/finding-simple-step-and-continuous-functions-to-satisfy-lebesgue-integral-cond)

The author of the chosen answer proves that for the characteristic function $[E ]$ and $\epsilon >0$, there is a continuous function $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to [0,1]$ such that $\displaystyle\int |[ E]-\phi|<\epsilon$, but he uses the regularity which is only valid if $E$ is of **finite measure**.

Is this still valid if $E$ isn't of finite measure? Or at least, I'm trying to do the case when $E$ is $\sigma$-finite, because I'm interested when $E=\mathbb{R}$.

Any suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\mathbb{R}=\bigcup_i [-i,+i]$.

**1st ingredient:**

For all $i\geq 1$, find continuous $g_i$ supported on $[-i,+i]$ s.t. $\int_{[-i,+i]} \left|f-g_i \right| < \frac{1}{i}$.

This is possible thanks to the proof in the link you provided.

**2nd ingredient:**

Now since $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue-integrable, $\int_{\mathbb{R}-[-i,+i]}|f|\rightarrow0$ as $i\rightarrow\infty$.

Can you conclude the argument using those ingredients?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get it. I understand that if $\epsilon _i >0$ then exists $i$ such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus{[-i,i]}}|f|<\epsilon _i$. And then maybe that would imply $\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f-g_i|<\epsilon$, but I don't see what $\epsilon_i$ would be chosen.

Comment: Sorry Seong, but I don't know how to tag you. I hope you'll see this.

Comment: Let $\epsilon>0$. Let $i$ be big enough such that $i<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Use 1st ingredient: pick $g_i$ supported on $[-i,+i]$ which $L^1$-approximates $f$ by $\frac{1}{i}$ (and thus by $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$).

Comment: Now use ingredient 2 to find $i^\prime$ such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}-[-i^\prime,+i^\prime]}|f| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

Comment: Then, we define $j=max\{i,i^\prime\}$ and decompose the integral $\int |f-g_j| = \int_{[-j,+j]}|f-g_j| + \int_{\mathbb{R}-[-j,+j]}|f|$...

Comment: Hope there was no typo... The LaTex parser is not working atm.

Comment: I don't get why $\int |f-g_j|=\int_{[-j,+j]|f-g_j|}+\int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus{[-j,+j]}}|f|$...

Shouldn't it be $\int |f-g_j|=\int_{[-j,+j]|f-g_j|}+\int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus{[-j,+j]}}|f-g_j|$?

Comment: That's the key point here. That's because $g_j$ is supported on $[-j,+j]$. i.e. $g_j=0$ on $\mathbb{R}-[-j,+j]$.

Comment: In the link I provided, the autor says that $\phi\restriction_{U^c}=0$, where $U$ is an open set and $E\subseteq U$. In this problem we would take $E=[-j,j]$. But I don't see why $g_j=0$ on $\mathbb{R}\setminus E$ (namely $E^c$).