# Show that $\mathtt d(A,B)>0$ if $A\cap B=\varnothing$, $A$ is compact and $B$ is closed.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I have this problem:

> If $X$ is a metric space, and if $A,B\subseteq X$ then the distance between $A$ to $B$ is $\mathtt d(A,B):=\inf \{d_X(x,y)| x\in A,y\in B\}$. Show that $\mathtt d(A,B)>0$ if $A\cap B=\varnothing$, $A$ is compact and $B$ is closed. What happen or if $B$ is open instead of closed? ans if $A$ is only closed instead of compact?

For the first claim, suppose that $\mathtt d(A,B)\not\gt 0\rightarrow\mathtt d(A,B)=0$, so $\inf \{d_X(x,y)| x\in A,y\in B\}=0$, then there's at least one $x\in A$ such that this happens, now we take the $\mathtt d(x,B):=\inf_{z\in B}d_X(x,z)=0$, I already proved that if that last distance is $0$ and the set is closed then $x\in B$, hence $x\in A\lor x\in B$ wich is a contradiction.


For the second claim, I'm not so sure, I think that in this case the $\inf$ doesn't exists, if we suppose that $\mathtt d(A,B)=\beta>0$ then doing something similar to the above, there's a $y_1\in B$ such that $\mathtt d(y_1,A)=\beta$, on the other hand since $B$ is open then $\exists\; \varepsilon_1>0$ such that $B_X(y_1,\varepsilon_1)\subseteq B$, so there's a $y_2\in B_X(y_1,\varepsilon_1)$ such that for some $0<\varepsilon_2<\varepsilon_1$ then $\mathtt d(y_2,A)+\varepsilon_2=\beta$, then $\mathtt d(y_2,A)<\mathtt d(y_1,A)$, so there is a smaller number than $\beta$. I think I'm taking to much liberty with the $y_2$.


For the third I belive that you just have to give a counterexample, however I'm having trouble finding it. I was thinking maybe something like a line in $\Bbb R^2$ that gets really close to another line, like asymptotically, but I don't know if it'll really work with any metric space.

Comment: For the "what if" parts, all you need is to give counterexamples. Under the conventional definition of line, your two lines idea will not work. But a small modification will, such as one set the $x$-axis, the other the curve $y=1/x$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Do I have to prove that $x$-axis and $1/x$ hyperbola are closed? When a problem says "Prove that in general _blah_ doesn't happen if _bleh_ happens" you just have to give a counterexample?

Comment: Well, the fact that they are closed is pretty obvious, but you should at least *say* that they are closed. Unfortunately, I cannot give you a general answer. It depends on the level of detail demanded by the instructor.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. But now, with the counterexample for the 2nd claim, I thought maybe taking $X=\Bbb R$, $A=[0,1]$, $B=(2,3)$, then the infimum distance is 1, but there isn't any elements in A and B that satisfaces that, is it ok?

Comment: I think you want say $A=[0,1]$ and $B=(1,2)$.

Comment: Unfortunately, your argument for the first part is at best very incomplete. You have not even used compactness. I am reluctant  to write an answer, since this question has been asked and answered several times on MSE. [Here is one place.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109167/if-a-is-compact-and-b-is-closed-show-da-b-is-achieved) There are others even closer. You are probably much better than I am at searching.

Comment: that is better, thanks. I know! That's why I don't feel well about what I wrote, obviously somewhere we have to use compactness, and I found this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109167/if-a-is-compact-and-b-is-closed-show-da-b-is-achieved , however they end up proving this when both sets are compact, I don't understan why they do that

Comment: Typing mathematics of any length in comments is painful, so I have given a fairly detailed sketch of an answer for the first part.

Comment: See also: [A and B disjoint, A compact, and B closed implies there is positive distance between both sets.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/48714)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have discussed the last two parts in comments. For the first part, suppose $d(A,B)=0$. Then there is a sequence $(a_n,b_n)$ of ordered pairs, where $a_n\in A$ and $b_n\in B$, such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}d(a_n,b_n)=0$. Because $A$ is compact, the sequence $(a_n)$ has a convergent subsequence $(a_{n_i})$ with limit $a\in A$. Now consider the sequence $(b_{n_i})$. By using the Triangle Inequality, we can show that it has limit $a$. Since $B$ is closed, we have $a\in B$, contradicting the fact that  $A\cap B=\emptyset$.