# Distance between two disjoint closed subsets of the real numbers

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$ and $B$ be disjoint closed subsets of $\mathbb R^n$. Define $d(A,B)=\inf\{\left\|a-b\right\|\colon a \in A \text{ and } b \in B\}$.

I have to show that if $A=\{a\}$ is a singleton, then $d(A,B) > 0$.

Also I am not sure how to show that if $A$ is compact, $d(A,B) > 0$.

Also I don't know how to find an example of two disjoint closed sets in $\mathbb R^2$ with $d(A,B) =0$.

Comment: Hint: suppose $A=\{a\}$ is a singleton, and d(A,B)=0. Then we can pick a sequence $b_n \in B$ such that $d(a,b_n)$ tends to 0 as n tends to infinity. Conclude from this that $a \in B$. That's a contradiction (why?). So we must have d(A,B) > 0.

Comment: @jflipp I still do not really understand..

Comment: Which part of the hint don't you understand?

Comment: Never mind I figured it out! THank you

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, please see jfilpp's comment.

For your second question, i.e. $A$ is compact, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/531346/prove-that-if-a-is-compact-and-b-is-closed-and-a-cap-b-emptyset-then).

Here is an example for your last question: $A=\mathbb{R}\times\{0\},B=\{(x,y)|xy=1\}$. These are closed disjoint sets, but $dist(A,B)=0$ (consider $(n,0)\in A, (n,\frac{1}{n})\in B$ ).