# Existence of sequences whose limit is infimum

Tags: metric-spaces, self-learning

Im trying to understand the proofs of this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391396/for-two-disjoint-compact-subsets-a-and-b-of-a-metric-space-x-d-show-that?noredirect=1&lq=1)  or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/414122/2-questions-regarding-compactness-and-closed?noredirect=1&lq=1).

> Let $(E,d)$ be a metric space. Let $A$, $B$ be two disjoint non-empty
>   subsets of $E$ with $A$ compact and $B$ closed. Show that $dist(A,B):=\inf\{d(x,y): x\in A, y\in B\}>0$

Poof begins supposing $dist(A,B)=0$. **Then  it implies that there are of  sequences $\{a_n\}$ in A and $\{b_n\}$ in B, with $d(a_n,b_n) \rightarrow 0$**.

I really don't understand why is that. Could someone explain to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

Let $E=\{d(a,b) \; : \; (a,b)\in A\times B\}$.

then $d(A,B)=\inf E$.

the characterisation of the infimum gives

$$\forall \epsilon>0 \;\; \exists e\in E \; : \; d(A,B)\le e<d(A,B)+\epsilon$$

$$\iff$$
$$\forall n\in \Bbb N \; \exists e_n\in E \; : \; 0\le e_n< \frac{1}{n+1}$$

thus $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}e_n=0$$
but the existence of $e_n$ is equivalent to the existence of $(a_n,b_n)\in A\times B$ such that $e_n=d(a_n,b_n)$.

Comment: As far as I know, the existence of such $e \in E$ is valid for real numbers. You used it because the image of a metric is real?

Comment: @Danmat Yes E is a subset of $\Bbb R^+$.

Comment: Wow I completely understand it now. You constructed a sequence in the image of $d$ in the form $d(a_n,b_n)$ for each $n$, and show that this converges in $\mathbb{R_+}$

Comment: @Danmat Thanks a lot . You made me happy. Thanks once again.