# For two subspaces $E$ and $X$ of $H^1(\mathbb{R},\rho)$ with $E\cap X=\{0\}$, show that $d(E,S(X)) = C_d > 0$

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, hilbert-spaces

Let $\rho$ be the standard Gaussian measure and let $h\in H^1(\mathbb{R},\rho)$ be such that $\exp h \in H^1(\mathbb{R},\rho)$. By Sobolev embeddings, we have $H^1(\mathbb{R},\rho)\hookrightarrow C^0(\mathbb{R})$. Let $X$ be the linear subspace of $H^1(\mathbb{R},\rho)$ given by
$$
X = \{ u \in H^1(\mathbb{R},\rho) \ |\  u(0) = 0\}.
$$
Now consider the ODE
$$
u' - u\, h' = 0.
$$
All possible solutions to this differential equation form the one-dimensional linear space $E = \{c\,\exp h \ | \ c\in\mathbb{R}\}$. Denote by $S(X) = \{u\in X \ |\ \Vert u\Vert_{H^1} = 1 \}$ the unit sphere in $X$.

My questions are the following:

1. Does a sequence $\{u_n\}\subset H^1(\mathbb{R},\rho)$ with $\Vert u'_n - u_n\, h'\Vert_{H^1} \to 0$ imply that there exists some $c\in\mathbb{R}$, such that $\Vert u_n - c\, \exp h\Vert_{H^1} \to 0$.
2. Is there a way to show, that there exists some positive constant $C_d>0$, such that
   $$
   \operatorname{dist}_{H^1}(S(X),E)
   = \inf_{u\in S(X)}\inf_{\eta\in E} \Vert u-\eta \Vert_{H^1}
   \geq C_d > 0.
   $$

**Note:**
There is a related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391396/for-two-disjoint-compact-subsets-a-and-b-of-a-metric-space-x-d-show-that) but the assumptions are a
little different. Here, $E$ is closed, convex and finite
dimensional while $S(X)$ is closed and bounded but not
convex and infinite dimensional.

Here is what I tried so far: Due to the Sobolev embedding, we have for any $c \in \mathbb{R}$
$$
\inf_{u\in S(X)} \Vert u- c\,\exp h \Vert_{H^1}
\geq C_\mathrm{Sob} \inf_{u\in S(X)} \Vert u- c\,\exp h \Vert_{C^0}
\geq C_\mathrm{Sob} \inf_{u\in S(X)} \vert u(0) - c\,\exp h(0) \vert
= C_\mathrm{Sob} \exp h(0) \vert c\vert.
$$
In other words $\operatorname{dist}(E,S(X)) \gtrsim  \inf_{c\in\mathbb{R}} \vert c\vert$. On the other hand, we have for $\{c_n\, \exp h\}_n \subset E$ with $c_n\to 0$
$$
\inf_{u\in S(X)} \Vert u- c_n\,\exp h \Vert_{H^1}
\geq \inf_{u\in S(X)} \vert \Vert u \Vert_{H^1} - \vert c_n\vert \Vert \exp h \Vert_{H^1} \vert
= \vert 1 - \vert c_n\vert \Vert \exp h \Vert_{H^1} \vert
\to 1
\qquad\mbox{as }n\to \infty.
$$
Since not both these lower bounds can go to zero simultaneously, this yields some equilibrium value $0 < c^* < \Vert \exp h\Vert_{H^1}^{-1}$ such that e.g. $\operatorname{dist}(E,S(X)) \geq C_\mathrm{Sob} \exp h(0) c^* > 0$.