# Continuity of $d(x,A)$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I am doing a head-check here. I keep seeing this theorem quoted as requiring $A$ to be closed (as in [Is the distance function in a metric space (uniformly) continuous?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8066/is-the-function-distance-continuous)), but I don't think that it is needed.

> **Theorem.** Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $\emptyset \neq A\subseteq X$. Then $x \longmapsto d(x,A)$ is Lipschitz continuous.

Proof. Fix $x,y \in X$. We note that for any $a \in A$ we have $d(x,a) \leq d(x,y) + d(y,a)$.
Taking the infimum over $a \in A$ then gives $d(x,A) \leq d(x,y) + d(y,A)$. It follows quickly that
$$
|d(x,A)-d(y,A)| \leq d(x,y)
$$
and the claim is proved.

Have I accidentally used closedness of $A$ somewhere in my proof? I don't think it is necessary. Maybe the reason that it is usually quoted with $A$ closed is so that there is an $a \in A$ with $d(x,A) = d(x,a)$? (As @Martin points out, this also requires some compactness assumption on the unit ball, e.g. it holds if $X=\mathbb{R}^n$ with Euclidean metric)

Comment: Looks good! I suspect that is the reason that $A$ is sometimes assumed to be closed.

Comment: closedness is not needed for proving continuity. Even it is true if $d$ is pseudometric.

Comment: The closedness of $A$ is unnecessary for the theorem. But we can always assume so, because we always have $d(x, A) = d(x, \bar{A})$.

Comment: Closedness of $A$ is *not* sufficient for the existence of $a \in A$ such that $d(x,a) = d(x,A)$. You need some sort of compactness condition. Consider $A = \{(1+2^{-n})e_n \mid n \in \mathbb N\}$ in $\ell_2$ and $x = 0$.

Comment: You have not used any assumption about $A$ in this proof, except that it is non empty. It can be any non empty set.

Comment: @Martin Yes thank you for pointing that out. If $X=\mathbb{R}^n$ and $A$ is closed then what I said is true. (Proof uses compactness of unit ball).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Summarizing the comments and expanding slightly:

Yes, your argument is perfectly okay as it stands and you didn't make any hidden use of closedness of $A$ anywhere, only non-emptiness of $A$ is used to ensure that $d(\cdot,A)$ is a real-valued function.

A good additional exercise would be to show that $1$ is the best Lipschitz constant (unless $A$ is dense in $X$ where $d(\cdot,A) = 0$).

---

Why people often state this result for closed $A$ only is unclear to me, but I agree that it is quite common to make this unnecessary assumption. See for example [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/107530/49437) or [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/48850/49437) for further examples. The answers point out more or less explicitly that this is not needed.

It could be that the reason is related to the fact you mention---that the infimum is a minimum for closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, or, more generally, in metric spaces for which closed balls are compact. Another possible "reason" could be that $\overline{A} = \{x \in X \mid d(x,A) = 0\}$, which shows that a *closed* set $A$ can be recovered from the zero-set of $d(\cdot,A)$.