# Determining measures by integrals

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request

What classes of functions are sufficient to determine whether two measures are equal? If 
$$\int_{R^d} f d\mu =\int_{R^d} f d\nu $$
for some functions $f$, when can we say that $\mu=\nu$?
Obviously, if $f$ can be any indicator function this is easy but is there a theorem for continuous functions say? Also, what about if we integrate over more general spaces, e.g. a Banach space?

Thanks.

EDIT: Extra question - According to Stefan in the comments, in the special case that $(S,d)$ is a metric space and μ and ν are Borel probability measures, then the space of non-negative bounded and continuous functions works. Please can somebody suggest a good reference for this or a reason why this is true?

Comment: For what it's worth: If $(S,d)$ is a metric space, then the space of non-negative bounded and continuous functions has that property if you assume that $\mu$ and $\nu$ are Borel probability measures. If $S=\mathbb{R}^d$, then $\{x\mapsto e^{-n|x-a|^2}\mid n\in\mathbb{N},\,a\in\mathbb{R}^d\}$ is enough.

Comment: @Stefan: That is helpful to me thanks. Please could you recommend a reference?

Comment: *Probability Measures on Metric Spaces* by Parthasarathy is a good reference (in addition to Billingsley's book mentioned by Ju'x).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Let $(S,d)$ be a metric space and let $\mu$, $\nu$ be two Borel probability measures on $S$. Then
>   $$
> \int f\,\mathrm d\mu=\int f\,\mathrm d\nu,\;\forall\,f\in \mathrm{bC}(S)_+\iff\mu=\nu.
> $$

Proof: Assume that the integrals of every function in $\mathrm{bC}(S)_+$ are identical. Then to show $\mu=\nu$, it is enough to show that $\mu(U)=\nu(U)$ for all $U\subseteq S$ open. For each $n\geq 1$ we define
$$
f_n(x):=n\cdot d(x,U^c)\wedge 1,\quad n\geq 1.
$$
Then the $f_n$'s are bounded, non-negative and continuous (they are in fact Lipschitz continuous) and $f_n\uparrow 1_U$ pointwise. Thus,
$$
\mu(U)=\int 1_U\,\mathrm d\mu=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_n\,\mathrm d\mu=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_n\,\mathrm d\nu=\nu(U).
$$

---

We can relax the assumption that $\mu$ and $\nu$ need to be probability measures. The above also holds in the more general setting where $\mu$ and $\nu$ are just measures such that there exists a sequence $(A_n)_{n\geq 1}$ of *open* Borel sets such that 
$$
S=\bigcup_{n\geq 1}A_n,\quad \text{and}\quad \mu(A_n)=\nu(A_n)<\infty,\quad n\geq 1.
$$

Comment: Thanks for this answer but where did you use the fact that $\mu$ and $\nu$ are probability measures? Also, I am a little confused about how you show that is Lipschitz (although it is probably trivial - it is in $R^d$ with open balls which is enough in that case).

Comment: @David: $d(x,F)$ for any subset $F$ of a metric space $X$ is Lipschitz. Look here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/48879/12690

Comment: @David: We used that $\mu$ and $\nu$ are probability measures when I said that it's enough to show $\mu(U)=\nu(U)$ for $U$ open. But this would also hold when just $\mu$ and $\nu$ are both finite measures.

Comment: @StefanHansen: I thought that just used that it is a Borel measure. ..Is there a counter example if the measures are not finite?

Comment: @David: You actually don't need them to be finite (see my edit). This uses a classical uniqueness result which relies on Dynkin's lemma, and I'm pretty sure we can't relax any further on the assumptions. But I can't give you a concrete counter example (maybe that is a new question?).

Comment: @StefanHansen: I don't completely understand but I will have a think about it. Please can you recommend a reference?

Comment: I don't have a reference for the first part, but _Measures, Integrals and Martingales_ by Schilling (Chapter 5) treats the uniqueness of measures.

Comment: @StefanHansen: Thanks. Billingsley's Convergence of Probability Measures as recommended by Ju'x has a reference for the first statement.

Answer (score 3):

If is enough to check the equality of integrals with $f(x) = e^{i\langle x,\theta\rangle}$ for every $\theta \in \Bbb R^d$. This is the *Fourier transform*.

The proofs of both this and the general result given by Stefan can be found in Billingsley's *Convergence of Probability Measures*.

Comment: What does $\langle x,\theta\rangle$ mean for you?

Comment: It is the scalar product $\langle x,\theta\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^d x_i \theta_i$.

Comment: S'circular argument