# Show that the function $f: X \to \Bbb R$ given by $f(x) = d(x, A)$ is a continuous function.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity, uniform-continuity

I'm studying for my Topology exam and I am trying to brush up on my metric spaces.

Suppose $(X, d)$ is a metric space and $A$ is a proper subset of $X$. Show that the function $f: X \to \Bbb R$ given by $f(x) = d(x, A)$ is a continuous function.

I know that showing the pre-image of an open set is open in $X$ is an option for continuity. Yet, I would like to know how to show continuity with open balls or neighborhoods given the context of the problem.

By the way, is this the Euclidean metric? Or am I jumping the gun a bit there?

Comment: Hint: $d(x,a) \leq d(x,y) + d(y,a)$, so $d(x,A) \leq d(x,y) + d(y,A)$.

Comment: I had to prove that in the previous portion of the problem, but I don't see the correlation between the two.

Comment: Improve this to $\lvert d(x,A) - d(y,A)\rvert \leq d(x,y)$, so $f$ is Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: Ahh, now that makes sense. Since the metric space has to satisfy the triangle inequality, I can create that relation. Thanks.

Comment: @Vergil: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for how to typeset common math expressions with LaTeX, and [see here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to use Markdown formatting.

Comment: @Landscape Thank you. I couldn't find that one.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: You are welcome. I just noticed that the linked question was answered by Martin not very long time before and he also commented here. I am a little curious why he didn't vote to close.

Comment: Check the definition of $d(x,A)$ the distance between a point and a set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Credits to [Martin](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/49437/martin).

> Fix $a\in A$. Since $d(x,a)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,a)$, taking $\inf\limits_{a\in A}$ we have that $$d(x,A)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,A)$$
> By symmetry (i.e. $d(y,x)=d(x,y)$) $$d(y,A)\leq d(x,y)+d(x,A)$$ which gives that $$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq d(x,y)$$
>
> Thus $f$ is $1-$Lipschitz continuous, whence it is continuous.$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\blacktriangle$

Comment: I would love to upvote this *and* reward you for the effort :-) For the future: if I comment, there's no need to make an answer CW...

Comment: @Martin It is *always* better to answer questions rather than to comment: this reduces the "UNANSWERED" list and gives you some rep!

Comment: @Martin Of course, if you want to give a reward you can always upvote other answers of mine ;)

Comment: In this case I was sure that it was a duplicate and I preferred to give a brief hint instead of trying to look for the duplicate. (You'll get your reward, but I have a lot to choose from :-)).

Comment: I'd rather take the hint than the answer. How do I upvote comments?

Comment: Hover to the leftmost of them, there is a triangle that should turn red. In this case, I think the hint and the answer almost give away the same!

Comment: Fair enough, and thanks. However, "whence" means "from where." Although that might have been a typo.

Comment: @Vergil I know what "whence" means. I am saying, "Since $f$ is Lipschitz continuous, it is continuous."