# Mapping on induced topology and distance metric

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space. Let $τ$  be the metric topology on $X$ induced by $d$. For
$A ⊆ X$ , let $d(x, A) := \inf_{a∈A}  d(x, a) $ for $x ∈ X$

(a) If $f (x) := d(x, A)$  (for a fixed subset A) then show that $f : (X, τ ) → R $ is a continuous mapping.

(b) If every infinite bounded set in $X$ has a limit point (in $X$) and $A$ is closed (in $(X, τ )$ ) then show that for each $x ∈ X$  there exists an element $a_0 ∈ A $ such
$d(x, A) = d(x, a_0)$.

I have no clue how should I even approach to this. A detailed solution would be great.

Comment: What's the context of this question? Where did you come across it?

Comment: I am learning Topology. I came across a sheet of problems on topological spaces and continuous functions in which this problem was mentioned.

Comment: I think that the question (a) has been asked (and answered) several times on this site; for example here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48850/continuity-of-the-metric-function, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/418042/show-that-the-function-f-x-to-bbb-r-given-by-fx-dx-a-is-a-continuo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part (a) has been asked and answered several times on this site, for example:

- [Continuity of the function $x\mapsto d(x,A)$ on a metric space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48850/continuity-of-the-metric-function)
- [Show that the function $f: X \to \Bbb R$ given by $f(x) = d(x, A)$ is a continuous function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/418042/show-that-the-function-f-x-to-bbb-r-given-by-fx-dx-a-is-a-continuo/418052#418052)

For the part (b), you can try proof by contradiction. Assume that $d(x,a)>d(x,A)$ for each $a\in A$. By the definition of infimum we have that for each positive integer $n$ there exists $a_n$ such that
$$d(x,a_n)<d(x,A)+\frac1n.$$
Now the set $\{a_n; n\in\mathbb N\}$ is infinite and bounded. (Can you explain why it is infinite and bounded?)

Then it has at least one limit point. Let us denote a limit point of this set by $a_0$. (In fact, this limit point is a limit of a subsequence of $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$.) What can you say about $a_0$?