# Prove that $f(x)=d(x,A)=\inf_{y\in A}d(x,y)$ is continuous on $M$

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity

> Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space, $A\subset M$. Prove that $$f(x)=d(x,A)=\inf_{y\in A}d(x,y)$$ is continuous on $M$.

I have tried the following

Let $\epsilon>0$, $x_0\in M$. I have to find $\delta>0$ such that if $d(x,x_0)<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$.

For that,

$$|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon\iff \big|\inf_{y\in A}d(x,y)-\inf_{y\in A}d(y,x_0)\big|<\epsilon \iff \big|\inf_{y\in A}\{d(x,y)-d(y,x_0)\}\big|<\epsilon$$
and I do not know how to continue.

Note: My teacher has not defined Lipschitz continuity.

Comment: Are you sure about the last equivalence?

Comment: @T'x no, but sup{A+B}=sup{A}+sup{B} and I suposse that inf{A-B}=inf{A}-inf{B}

Comment: no, i think you will easily find a counterexample for the inf's

Comment: See also [Continuity of the function $x\mapsto d(x,A)$ on a metric space](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/48850)

Answer (score 2):

Let $y \in A$. By the triangular inequality,
$$ d(x,A) \leq d(x,y) \leq d(x,x_0) + d(x_0,y)
$$
Therefore, $d(x,A) - d(x,x_0) \leq d(x_0,y)$. From this, you can conclude
$$ d(x,A) - d(x,x_0) \leq d(x_0,A)
$$
$$ d(x,A) - d(x_0,A) \leq d(x,x_0)
$$
Similarly $d(x_0,A) - d(x,A) \leq d(x,x_0)$. Taking absolute value,
$$ |d(x,A) - d(x_0,A)| \leq d(x,x_0)
$$
It is sometimes quite difficult to do algebra with $\inf$ and $\sup$. Understanding the fact that they are the lower and upper bounds will help.

Comment: It is not clear that $d(x,A)-d(x,x_0)\leq d(x_0,A)$

Comment: The equation $d(x,A) - d(x,x_0) \leq d(x_0,y)$ holds for all $y \in A$. Thus it holds for the infimum.