# Distance between a point to a set in metric spaces

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ be any arbitrary metric space. Now fix $y \in X$ and define $d_y: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, d_y(x)= d(x,y)$.

> How can I prove that $d_y$ is continuous on $X$? (Given any fixed $y
>  \in X$).

Also, let $A \subseteq X$ and fix $x \in X$, define $\rho(x, A) = \inf \{d(x,a) : a \in A \}$,

> Show that the closure of $A$ is $\overline{A}=\{x \in X: \rho(x, A)=0
>  \}$

Finally, let $A \subseteq X$ be a compact subset of $X$.

> Prove that $\rho(x, A) = d(x, a)$ for some $a \in A$.

Comment: Please, post only one question in one post. Posting several questions in the same post is discouraged and such questions may be put on hold, see [meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6464/posting-multiple-questions-as-one). Moreover at least some (probably all) questions from your post have been asked here before.

Comment: The third question was asked here: [For any point $a$ of a compact subset $S$ of a metric space, prove that there exists a nearest point $ c $ to $ a $.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/333479)

Comment: Some posts about the first question:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48850/continuity-of-the-function-x-mapsto-dx-a-on-a-metric-space
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/400487/continuity-of-dx-a
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1361610/prove-that-f-a-x-d-x-a-is-continuous
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1695885/prove-that-fx-is-continuous-on-m

Comment: For the second one see [In a metric $(X,d)$, prove that for each subset $A$, $x\in\bar{A}$ if and only if $d(x,A)=0.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/385127) and other posts [linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/385127).

Answer (score 4):

**Problem 1**

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be arbitrary, choose $\delta = \epsilon$, try to show that 
$$
d(x,z)<\delta\implies \lvert d_y(x) - d_y(z)\rvert < \varepsilon
$$
on your own.

**Problem 2**

Recall that the closure of $A$ is the union of $A$ and its limit points. This means that we need to show that if a point $x$ is a limit point of $A$, i.e. if there exists a sequence $(a_n)_n\subseteq A$ that converges to $x$, then $\rho(x,A) = 0$, and that if $\rho(x,A) = 0$, then we can find a sequence $(a_n)_n\subseteq A$ that converges to $x$.

To show the first direction, show that you can always find some $a\in A$ that is arbitrarily close to $x$ by using the given sequence $(a_n)_n$ that converges to $x$. To show the second, use the definition of infimum to try to show the existence of $a\in A$ that are arbitrarily close to $x$.

**Problem 3**

In metric spaces, compactness is the same as sequential compactness, meaning that every sequence in $A$ has a convergent subsequence that converges inside $A$. First show that you can construct a sequence $(a_n)_n\subseteq A$ so that $d(x,a_n)$ converges to $\rho(x,A)$. Then, show that this sequence $(a_n)_n$ is convergent (hint: compact spaces are complete). Finally, show that $a\in A$, the limit of $a_n$, satisfies $\rho(x,A) = d(x,a)$.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, is my attempt at Problem 3 correct as follows? 
Fix $x \in X$ and define the function $d_x: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, d_x(a) = d(x, a)$. By the first problem, this function is continuous on $A$ (for fixed $x \in X)$. So by the Extreme Value Theorem (we can apply it here since $A$ is compact), there exists $a^* \in A$ such that $d_x(a^*) = \inf_{a \in A} d_x(a) = \rho(x, A)$.

Comment: Sounds good! But are you sure you are allowed to use EVT? Seems like you haven't proven it yet, given the nature of the problems.