# About distance between a set and element

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

Ploblem:

For every nonempty set $A$ of a metric space $M$, define 
$A^*=\{x∈M: d(x,A)=0\}$. Prove that $(A^*)^* = A^*$.

Now by definition, the distance between $x$ and $A$ is
$d(x,A)=\inf\{d(a,x):x∈A\}$.
My question is how are the elements in $\inf\{d(a,x):x∈A\}=0$ ?
how can I take an element of this set?

Comment: Definitely a ploblem...

Comment: Note that $A \subset A^*$ to start. This gives $A^* \subset (A^*)^*$ 'for free'.

Comment: Show the opposite inclusion.

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: Pick an element of $(A^*)^*$ and show that it is in $A^*$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lemma:** $A^*$ is closed in $M$.

**Proof:** We show that $(A^*)^c$ is open in $M$. We have
$$
(A^*)^c=\{x\in M:d(x,A)>0\}
$$
Let $x\in(A^*)^c$. Then $\gamma:=d(x,A)>0$ and $B_M(x,\gamma/2)\subset(A^*)^c$. Indeed, for all $y\in B_M(x,\gamma/2)$ and for all $a\in A$, we have
\begin{align}
d(y,a)&\geq d(x,a)-d(x,y)\\
&>\gamma-\frac{\gamma}{2}\\
&=\frac{\gamma}{2}
\end{align}
hence $d(y,A)>\gamma/2>0$.

**Proof of $\subset$**: Let $x\in(A^*)^*$. Then $d(x,A^*)=0$ so there exists a sequence $(a_n)\subset A^*$ converging to $x$. Since $A^*$ is closed, $\lim a_n=x\in A^*$.

Comment: Thank you 'Guest', really appreciate it :)

Comment: @Jacob Schwartz You are welcome.

Comment: @Jacob Schwartz Alternatively, if you already know that [the function $x\mapsto d(x,A)$ is continuous](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48850/continuity-of-the-function-x-mapsto-dx-a-on-a-metric-space), then the Lemma is a one-liner since $A^*$ is the preimage of the closed subset $\{0\}$ of $\mathbb{R}$.