# The distance between two disjoint compact subsets $A,B$ of a metric space $X$ is positive

Tags: metric-spaces, proof-verification

Please tell me whether my argument for the following result is true:

> **The distance between two disjoint compact subsets $A,B$ of a metric space $X$ is positive:**
>
> $d:X\times X\to \mathbb R$ is continuous$\implies d|_{A\times B}$ is continuous on $A\times B$
>
> $A,B$ are compact $\implies A\times B$ is compact$\implies d|_{A\times B}$ assumes its minimum on $A\times B\implies\exists~a\in A,b\in B$ such that $$\inf_{x\in A,~y\in B} d|_{A\times B}(x,y)=d(a,b)>0.$$

Comment: There is no need to deal with the restriction on $d$, otherwise your proof is good.

Comment: Agreed, it's fine.

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48714/a-and-b-disjoint-a-compact-and-b-closed-implies-there-is-positive-distance-bet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to deal with restrictions of $d$. All that is necessary is to note that $A \times B $ is compact.

Let $m = \min_{a\in A, b\in B} d(a,b)$. If $m = 0$, then $m=d(a,b)$ for some $a \in A, b \in B$, and since $d(a,b) = 0$, we have $A \cap B \ne \emptyset$, a contradiction.

Comment: Sorry. Edited it.

Comment: Me too. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Could you please point where exactly did you use the fact that $A \times B$ is compact?

Comment: @Tomasz: To conclude that there is a point $(a,b)$ at which the distance is a $\min$.

Comment: How do we conclude that? Because compact spaces imply that every sequence has a limit point?

Comment: @math_beginner: A continuous function on a compact set achieves its $\max,\min$ value. One way of proving it is to take an accumulation point of an extremising sequence.