# Prove there is a minimum distance between a closed and compact sets.

Tags: calculus, general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $A$ be a compact set and $B$ a closed set ($\varnothing\ne A,B\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$). Prove there's a minimum distance between $A$ and $B$.

In class we've seen that there's a minimum distance between a compact set $A$, and a point $x_0\notin A$. I thought about utilizing it as a generalization.

First we may assume the points (if exist) must be on the spheres of the sets. For each $x_0$ in the sphere of $B$ there's a point $y_0$ in the sphere of  $A$ such that $\forall y\in A: \|y_0-x_0\| \le \|y-x_0\|$.

So we define $f:A\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = \text{minimumDistance(x,B)}$.

Is that a good start? How should I proceed?

Comment: By "sphere" do you mean "boundary"?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48714/a-and-b-disjoint-a-compact-and-b-closed-implies-there-is-positive-distance-bet?rq=1

Comment: @BaronVT, I guess so (I thought a "Sphere" is a well-known term)

Comment: Shouldn't $B$ be nonempty?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, that wan't mentioned but I guess we may assume this, otherwise this question has no meaning.

Comment: And also $A$, right?

Comment: Yes, both shouldn't be empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that in $\mathbb R^n$, closed bounded sets are exactly the compact sets.

$A$ is bounded, so we can set $B' = B\cap [-K,K]^n$ for sufficiently large $K$ so that all points in $B\setminus B'$ are far enough from $A$ (i.e. so that $d(A, B\setminus B')>d(a,b)$ for some fixed $a\in A$ and $b\in B$).

$B'$ is closed and bounded, so it's compact and there's a minimal distance between $A$ and $B'$ which remains minimal between $A$ and $B$ from the choice of $K$.

Far enough means that

Comment: I see you narrowed the problem to: distance between two compact sets and concluded immediately that there's a minimum between them. Why?

Comment: We've proved there's a minimum distance between a compact set and point.

Comment: Maybe we could define $f:A\to B'$ which returns the point in $B$ where the distance is minimal.

Comment: @AlonAlon Or maybe you use that continuous functions on a compact set attain a minimum?

Comment: Yes! Actually it was mentioned.

Comment: But what would be this function in our case?

Comment: By the way, how do you define $B'$ formally? (instead of "all points in $B- B'$ are far enough)?

Comment: @AlonAlon It's similar to the proof that a point has a minimum distance from a compact set. In this case, set $f(a)=d(a,B)$, then it has a minimum since $A$ is compact. You need that $d(a,B)$ is continuous in $a$, which follows from the generalized triangle inequality $d(a_1,B)\le d(a_1,a_2)+d(a_2,B)$.

Comment: OK, thank you @user2345215

Comment: But one more thing, how do you define $B'$ rigorously?

Comment: @AlonAlon I added the condition you need. Imagine $A$ sitting in a ball of radius $R$, then increase this radius by $d(a,b)$ for arbitrary $a\in A, b\in B$. This gives you the radius you need to ensure that $B$ outside of that is too far from $A$.

Comment: There's a technical problem; How do you define the function $f(a)=d(a,B)$? Is it the minimal distance or just distance? What is the domain?

Comment: Anyhow, I'm trying to prove $d(x,B)$ is continuous, but having hard times formalize this :/

Comment: @AlonAlon As I said, prove the triangle inequality I wrote about. It automatically implies the continuity.