# If $X$ is a compact subset of $M$, $y \in X'$, then there exists a point $a \in X$ such that $d(a,y) \leq d(x,y)$ for all $x \in X$

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

In exercise 43.7 of Johnsonbaugh/Pfaffenberger - Foundations of Mathematical Analysis, we seek to show that if $X \subset M$ is compact, then if $y \in X'$ then there exists a point $a \in X$ such that $d(a,y) \leq d(x,y)$ for all $x \in X$. Moreover, we are asked to show by example that this fails if $X$ is merely closed. I feel as if my proof does not work, since I cannot come up with a an example of a closed subset for which this fails. I've looked at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333479/for-any-point-a-of-a-compact-subset-s-of-a-metric-space-prove-that-there-ex/) question, and I think I understand how that works. However, I still fail to see how it would fail if $X$ were closed but not compact.

My "proof":

Suppose the conclusion fails, i.e. for any $a \in X$ there exists $x \in X$ such that $d(a,y) > d(x,y)$. Let $\{x_n\}$ be such a sequence in $X$. Then, since $X$ is compact, $\{x_n\}$ has a convergent subsequence, $\{x_{n,j}\}$. Since $X$ is compact, $lim_{j \to \infty}x_{n,j} = b$ is in $X$. But then $d(b,y) \leq d(x_{n,j},y)$ for all $x_{n,j}$. So we have the conclusion.

Comment: What is $X'$ here? And what is $M$?

Comment: You started with “Suppose the conclusion fails”. WHich contradiction did you obtain fram that assumption?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier the book doesn't specify in this example, but has used $X'$ to mean the complement of $X$ before, so I assumed it means that.

Comment: Weird but ok, and what is $M$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos the contradiction I think I produce is that I actually find a point in $X$ that satisfies the conclusion

Comment: No it doesn't, all $x_{n,j}$ doesn't mean all $x$.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier edited to clarify, $M$ is some arbitrary metric space containing $X$

Comment: @ArnaudMortier ah okay, thank you

Comment: @Clayton I'm sorry, I'm not sure I follow. If one of two subsets is compact and the other at least closed, the existence of a minimum *distance* is guaranteed?

Comment: If $d$ is induced by a norm, then it will be true. Indeed, if $d(x,y)=\mathcal N(x-y)$ and $x_n$ is a sequence s.t. $d(x_n,y) \underset{n\to \infty }{\longrightarrow } \inf_{x\in X}d(x,y)$ (of course, we suppose $X\neq\emptyset$), then in particular, $\mathcal N(x_n)\leq \mathcal N(x_n-a)+\mathcal N(a)$ and since $\mathcal N(x-n-a)$ is bounded, the sequence will be bounded, and thus will admit a subsequence that converge. I guess (but not sure), a metric as [Poincaré metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_metric) may work.

Comment: @perpetuallyconfused: Sorry, I think you need $M$ to be a complete metric space (or something like that). See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1101530/43239) for a reference to what I was considering.

Comment: The notation $X'$ more commonly means the derived set of $X$, rather than the complement of $X$, which is more commonly denoted by $X^c$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $M=[-1,0)\cup(0,1]$. Let $Y=\{-1\}$ and $X=(0,1]$. Note that $X$ is closed in $M$ since $[0,1]\cap M=X$. Now for $y\in Y$, $d(X,y):=\inf_{x\in X} d(x,y)=1$ while $d(x,y)>1$ for any fixed $x\in X$. Thus, there is no $x\in X$ for which the minimum distance is obtained.

The fatal flaw in your proof to being able to generalize to closed sets is that you are using the fact that in a metric space, a sequence in a compact set always has a convergent subsequence. This is not true if the set is merely closed.

Comment: Thanks! I thought that might be the linchpin, but as the proof as a whole was faulty and I didn't think of such an example, I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

For a counter-example when $X$ is closed but not compact, let $M=\Bbb Q$ with $d(x,y)=|x-y|.$ Let $X=M\cap (\sqrt 2\;, \infty)$ and $y=0.$

For a counter-example when, also, $d$ is a complete metric, let $M=\Bbb R\cup \{y\}$ where $y\not\in \Bbb R.$ For $u,v\in \Bbb R$ let $d(u,v)=\frac {|u-v|}{1+|u-v|}.$ For $u\in \Bbb R$ let $d(u,y)=2-d(u,0).$ And let $X=\Bbb R.$

Comment: There are also examples from functional analysis but you need to read a book on that first.