# $A$ and $B$ disjoint and closed implies there is positive distance between both sets

Tags: real-analysis

I recently came across this question: [A and B disjoint, A compact, and B closed implies there is positive distance between both sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48714/a-and-b-disjoint-a-compact-and-b-closed-implies-there-is-positive-distance-bet)

> Do a and b always have a positive distance for a belonging to A and b belonging to B?

I was wondering if this theory also applies if both A and B were closed? Both of them both part of a metric space.

My intuition says no but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: are they inside an arbitrary metric space? in $\mathbb R^n$? What is the enviorment?

Comment: Both a subset of a metric space X

Answer (score 1):

The answer for arbitrary metric spaces is no, for example consider the space $\mathbb R\setminus {0}$ and take the clopen sets $\mathbb R^+$ and $\mathbb R^-$.

The answer for real or complex normed vector spaces of finite dimension is yes, because closed balls are compact ( consequence for the equivalence of norm theorem). The answer for arbitrary vector spaces is no, finally it is true for convex sets inside Hilbert spaces.