# $\inf{d(x,y);x∈A, y∈B}>0$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

Let $A$ be a subset of sequence of points which converges to point a∈$R^n$.  For a closed subset $B$ of $\mathbb R^n$ satisfying closure of $A$ and $B$ has no intersection,can we say $\inf{d(x,y);x∈A, y∈B}>0$?
I guess true, but I cannot proof this..
Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

P.S
Sorry,the first question was trivial..**closure of A** and B has no intersection, sorry..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$A$ and $B$ disjoint and closed implies there is positive distance between both sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2064328/a-and-b-disjoint-and-closed-implies-there-is-positive-distance-between-both)

Comment: Consider $n=1$, and $B=[0,1]$ so closed and $A=(1,2)$.  Then the infimum is $0$ near $1$

Comment: Take $A$ to be the graph of $y=\frac1x$ and $B$ to be the $x$-axis in $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Is only $B$ closed, or are both $A$ and $B$ closed?

Comment: What does close mean here? Compact and without boundary or any limit point belongs to the set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider the closed set $B=\{(x,0): x\in\mathbb{R}\}\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ and $A=\{(0,1/n): n\geq1\}\subset\mathbb{R}^2$. Then $\inf_{x\in A, y\in B}d(x,y)=0$.

If both $A,B$ are closed, this is still not true (Brian's comment provides a counter-example).

On the other hand: the result is true if one set is closed and the other is compact.