# Distance between closed set $A$ and compact set $B$ s.t. $A\cap B=\emptyset.$

Tags: analysis, solution-verification

I have to prove this statement.

> Let A and B be **nonempty disjoint** subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ where A is **closed** and B is **compact**. Then there exist $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ such that $\inf\{|a-b| | a \in A, b \in B\}=|a-b|$.

This is the question in [Distance between sets with one closed set and one compact set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2212496/distance-between-sets-with-one-closed-set-and-one-compact-set).

I'm trying to complete the proof referring to the questioner's idea and the two answers, but I'm having difficulty in completing the proof.

---

Let $E=\{|a-b| | a \in A, b \in B\}$.

And I can find the sequence $\{x_n\}\subset E$ s.t. $\lim x_n=\inf E$, since $E$ is not empty. (If $E$ is not bounded below, I consider $\inf E$ as $-\infty$.)

Since each $x_n$ is in $E$, there exist $\{a_n\}\subset A, \{b_n\}\subset B$ s.t. $x_n=|a_n-b_n|$

(Up to here, the questioner's idea. And from here, I refer to
the **Hagen's** answer.)

From the compactness of $B$, there exists a subsequence $\{b_{n_k}\}$ of $\{b_n\}$ and exists $b\in B$ s.t. $\lim_k b_{n_k}=b.$ ($b$ is called a limit point of $\{b_n\}$.)

Then, the **zwim's** answer says

> $(\ast)$ we can work locally in the disk of center $b$ and radius $r$ (large enough so it intersects $A$ but more importantly contains the convergent part of $(a_n)$)

I have not fully understood this.

Since $\lim_k b_{n_k}=b,$ for all $r>0$, there exists $k_0\in \mathbb N$ s.t. $k\geqq k_0 \Rightarrow |b_{n_k}-b|<r,$ i.e., $k\geqq k_0 \Rightarrow b_{n_k}\in B_r(b)$.

According to $(\ast)$, it appears that I have to choose $r$ so that $B_r(b)$ can interact $A$ and contain the convergent part of $\{a_n\}$.

However, I don't know what "the convergent part of $\{a_n\}$" means.

$\{a_n\}$ is in $A$ and $A$ is not necessarily bounded, so this doesn't necessarily have the convergent subsequence, and I don't know how I should choose $r$ specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $x:=\inf E=\lim x_n$ is finite since your $E$ is a non-empty subset of $[0,+\infty).$

There exists $k_0\in\mathbb N$ such that
$$k\geq k_0\Rightarrow |b_{n_k}-b|<1.$$

Then, there exists $k_1\ge k_0$ such that $$k\ge k_1\Rightarrow x_{n_k}<x+1,$$
hence
$$k\ge k_1\Rightarrow |a_{n_k}-b|<r:=x+2.$$