# Compact set around compact set

Tags: general-topology

Let $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set, and $K\subseteq E$ compact.

> Can I find $K'$ compact such that $K'\subseteq E$ and such that there exists $\epsilon >0$ with the property that $\forall x \in K$, $B_{\epsilon}(x) \subseteq K'$?

My try: $d:=\text{dist}(E^c,K)>0$ because $K$ is compact, $E^c$ is closed and they're disjoint ([A and B disjoint, A compact, and B closed implies there is positive distance between both sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48714/a-and-b-disjoint-a-compact-and-b-closed-implies-there-is-positive-distance-bet)).

Therefore I could take $\epsilon:=d/2$ and $K':=\overline{\cup_{x \in K}B_{\epsilon}(x)}$. It is obvious that $K'$ is closed and bounded, however I'm having an hard time proving it is contained in $E$.

Do you perhaps have any hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, $r\equiv d(K,\mathbb R^{n} \setminus E) >0$. So we can take $K'=\{x : d (x,K) \leq \frac r  2\}$. $K'$ is contained in $E$, it is compact and we can take $\epsilon =\frac r  2$.

Note that if $x \in K'$then (by compactness of $K$) there exists $y \in K$ such that $d(x,y) \leq \frac r 2$.  If $x \notin E$ then $r=d(K, \mathbb R^{n}\setminus E) \leq d(y, x) \leq \frac r 2$ which is a contradiction. This proves that $K'$ is contained in $E$.

Comment: OP seems to ask specifically about how to proof $K’$ is contained in $E$, so that should be spelled out I think.

Comment: @Milten I added a detailed proof.