# A closed set and compact set in topological vector space

Tags: topological-vector-spaces

I have read the post in the link: [A and B disjoint, A compact, and B closed implies there is positive distance between both sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48714/a-and-b-disjoint-a-compact-and-b-closed-implies-there-is-positive-distance-bet)

I wonder that the property in the link above is still correct in topological vector space or not? It means: If $A$ is closed, B is compact and $A\cap B = \varnothing$ then exist $V$ is neighborhood of $\theta$ that $$(A+V)\cap(B+V)=\varnothing$$

Comment: See Theorem 1.10 in Rudin's FA.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you a lot. I have found the answer in the book you mention.